# Como ejecutar métodos de clase hija usando instancia de clase padre

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy utilizando Laravel el cual contiene un clase del framework llamada User. Estoy desarrollando un paquete para lo cual declaro una clase UserHija con métodos propios, que hereda de User. En cierto momento necesito usar una función del framework que devuelve una instancia de la clase User, pero necesito ejecutar los métodos de mi clase UserHija.

La clase User viene con el framework, la cual no deseo modificar. Me referiré a ella como UserPadre.

Este es un resumen de mi clase hija, para hacerlo mas pequeño comparto solo un método.

```
use App\Models\User as UserPadre;
class User extends UserPadre

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function roles(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('Edelrojas\Access\Models\Role');
    }
}
```

En cierto momento utilizo un evento de laravel el que cual se lanza cuando un usuario se loguea. Ese evento lo capturo con un listener propio el cual recibe, por parte del framework un obj UserPadre. En este listener yo necesito acceder a los métodos de UserHijo(método roles), que solo tiene como diferencia de UserPadre varios métodos como por ejemplo roles.

La cuestión es que estoy desarrollado una serie de paquetes y entre menos código propio del framework se necesite variar seria mejor.

Hay alguna forma de hacer una especie de casting usando la clase User, para convertirla en UserHija y poder ejecutar mis métodos propios?
Cualquier otra idea para resolver el problema también la agradecería.

Comment: *En cierto momento necesito usar una función del framework que **devuelve una instancia de la clase User**, pero necesito ejecutar **los métodos de mi clase UserHija*** ... Estamos más bien ante un problema en la lógica de tu programa, para resolverlo lo que tienes que hacer es devolver una instancia de la clase que necesitas, no de la clase padre. Por ejemplo, ¿de dónde vas a sacar los **atributos propios de la clase hija en ese contexto**, lo cuales de por sí no estarán en la clase padre, si has planteado correctamente tu modelo de datos?

Comment: Hola. No puedes sobreescribir la función que mencionas? Trata de mostrar la parte del código involucrado en el llamado. En abstracto sólo podemos lanzar opiniones al vacío.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo entender que si el método debe devolver algo de la clase A puede devolver en su lugar una hija de A (sin conflicto) pero el enunciado de la pregunta no es preciso.

Comment: @quevedo en el planteamiento se dice que devuelve una instancia de la clase padre, pero que quiere usar métodos de la clase hija, lo suyo en ese caso es devolver una instancia de la clase hija directamente que heredará tanto los métodos/propiedades de la clase padre como aquellos propios de la clase hija. Me parece que es el camino correcto, pues lo contrario no tendría sentido ni podría hacerse sin recurrir a procedimientos que rompan los principios de la POO. Tener una dificultad en ese punto revela un mal planteamiento en la lógica del problema o un desconocimiento de la herencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano **totalmente de acuerdo** por eso le pregunto por la posibilidad de sobreescribir el método que llama para hacer que devuelva una hija. Y, le sugiero que muestre el contexto para poder hacer una propuesta de modificación...

Comment: Leyendo las adiciones que hiciste te sugiero: agregar a tu clase hija un método público autoExtend(UserParent $obj) que te permita transportar lo necesario. En el evento que atrapas con el listener inyectas la clase padre en una instancia de la hija, tomas de aquella todo lo necesario y continuas haciendo uso de la tuya. (Como conoces la estructura de la clase Padre puedes ajustar los métodos necesarios para pasar lo que sea significativo)

Comment: @quevedo. gracias por la ayuda. lo que me propones seria crear en el listener la instancia de la clase hija y en el constructor por ejemplo pasarle la instancia de la padre y guardarla en un variable.?

Comment: El listener activa el método que crea instancia de la clase padre, si la pasas a una instancia de la clase hija y tomas de la padre lo que se necesite para que la hija sea funcional puedes continuar.

Comment: perfecto @quevedo buena idea, me sirvio para mi caso. muchas gracias.